# Problem when running Servo library with thread (Protothreads)

Tags: arduino-uno, threads, platformio

When running two threads, one for blinking led once every second, one for sweeping the servo 180 degrees. The servo just vibrates.

When I tested adding a serial printout in the run servo for loops for the pos variable it worked but a bit jerky. Any idea what could be the problem?

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <pt.h>
#include <Servo.h>

// put function declarations here:
static struct pt pt1;
static struct pt pt2;
Servo myservo;
int pos = 0;

static int protothreadBlinkLED(struct pt *pt) {
  static unsigned long lastTimeBlink = 0;
  PT_BEGIN(pt);
  while(1) {
    lastTimeBlink = millis();
    PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, millis() - lastTimeBlink > 1000);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    lastTimeBlink = millis();
    PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, millis() - lastTimeBlink > 1000);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  }
  PT_END(pt);
}

static int protoThreadRunServo(struct pt *pt) {
  static unsigned long lastServoUpdate = 0;
  PT_BEGIN(pt);
  while(1) {
    lastServoUpdate = millis();
    for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1) {
      PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, millis() - lastServoUpdate > 150);
      myservo.write(pos);      
    }
    for(pos = 180; pos >= 1; pos -= 1) {    
      PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, millis() - lastServoUpdate > 150);
      myservo.write(pos);
    }
  }
  PT_END(pt);
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  myservo.attach(9);
  PT_INIT(&pt1);
  PT_INIT(&pt2);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  protothreadBlinkLED(&pt1);
  protoThreadRunServo(&pt2);
}
```

Comment: use `PT_SLEEP`, instead of `millis()`, as in example code ... `PT_SLEEP` is non-blocking